# convert old timestamp data in mysql date_i18n

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a field in mysql table with unix 10 digit timestamp records.  How do I convert the existing timestamp strings within mysql (sql not php) to date_i18n?

Comment: You could bring it in to word press

Comment: I tried importing to WP but this is why I need to convert the data first because when I import the field to WP it does not recognize the date properly. It converts the year totally wrong.  If I just display the original timestamp data from any of the records on a page using php it works properly so I know the timestamp data is not corrupted.